# Initialization in list - default value

Tags: c++, initialization

I've got this code sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Polygon
{
private:
    double _Field;

public:
    Polygon(): _Field(){}
    void show_field(){ cout << _Field << endl; }
};

 int main()
 {
     Polygon P1;

     P1.show_field();
     return 0;
 }
```

I'm just wondering why does show() method always shows me 0 value? Does initialization in list

```
Polygon(): _Field(){}
```

initialize given field with 0 by default if there is no argument present?

Comment: Yes, for built-in types

Comment: double is default initialized to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. Just like

```
double d = double();
double *p = new double();
```

will initialize `d` with `0` and allocate `*p` initialized with `0`.

The `()` initializer stands for *value-initialization* in C++, which boils down to zero-initialization for scalar types. It is not in any way restricted to constructor initializer lists. It can be used in a variety of other contexts.

It worked that way in C++ since the beginning of standardized times, except that in pre-C++03 versions of the language there was no such thing as *value-initialization*. In C++98 the `()` initializer triggered *default-initialization*, which also zeroed-out scalar types.

In modern C++ (C++11 and later) you can use `{}` initializer instead of `()` initializer to achieve the same effect. With `{}` you can also do

```
double d{};
```

which declares variable `d` initialized with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `_Field()` you perform a [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) I believe.